# Asterisk binary data transfer

Tags: sip, asterisk

The aim is to transfer raw binary data from one sip client to another using our Asterisk server. The problem is that sometimes it changes the data to unreadeable format (just raw binary data). Why it may be so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because SIP is not intended to do binary data transfer per RFC. SIP is a plaintext format and sending binary data is not compliant.

if you **really** need to use SIP for binary data transfer, you should use BASE64 to encode/decode your data when passing it through the SIP messaging.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now it is interesting to know - how did you know that - where did you read it - a book, an article ? Where can I get more info? Or it is just your practice? \

Comment: I think the more interesting question is where you got the idea to use SIP as a general purpose transport protocol? :-) Seriously: SIP is described in a few RFC documents that are free for everyone to read. They usually start with a high level overview you could read first. The current version is http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt

Comment: And using base64 is just a sign of having been around since the time when we had to do this manually for e-mail and usenet posts ;-)

Comment: Hi! I don`t need to make transport from sip. My problem is that sending some data (encrypted voice) using my asterisk server and using standart codecs (which of course don`t know anything about the format of transfered data) very often asterisk don`t let the data to be transfered. I don`t know where is the problem.

Comment: okay .. lets first sort some things out:
- SIP is a plaintext protocol for signalling, i.e. call setup
- RTP is a udp based binary protocol, used for the transporting of voice packets in VoIP networks. The details for an RTP session are subject to the mentioned SIP signalling.

If I understand you correctly, you try to send encrypted data from A to B, passing it over the asterisk. This doesn't work, because the standard codec you use generally has a specific format that doesn't match your binary data. if it does, that just luck.
When you want encrypted voice data, why dont you use SRTP?

Comment: but rfc 3261 in 7.4.1  says:-SIP messages MAY contain binary bodies or body parts. When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes
   of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of
   "UTF-8".

Comment: rfc 3261 in 27.5:-  Encoding scheme: SIP messages consist of an 8-bit header
         optionally followed by a binary MIME data object.  As such, SIP
         messages must be treated as binary.  Under normal circumstances
         SIP messages are transported over binary-capable transports, **no
         special encodings are needed.***

Comment: @Rahul_cs12 while that's true for rfc3261 as in "SIP messages relayed by a SIP proxy", this must not necessarily apply for asterisk because it is a "back to back user agent". read on: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+not-proxy